# Implicit array casting in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I have the following classes with an implicit cast operator defined:

```
class A
{
    ...
}
class B
{
    private A m_a;

    public B(A a)
    {
        this.m_a = a;
    }

    public static implicit operator B(A a)
    {
        return new B(a);
    }
}
```

Now, I can implicitly cast A to B.

But why can't I implicitly cast A[] to B[] ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // compiles
    A a = new A();
    B b = a;

    // doesn't compile
    A[] arrA = new A[] {new A(), new A()};
    B[] arrB = arrA;
}
```

Thanks, Malki.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Mehrdad Afshari mentioned, you're out of luck doing this implicitly. You'll have to get explicit, and it'll involve an array copy. Thankfully, you can probably do it with a one-liner:

```
arrB = arrA.Cast<B>().ToArray();
```

Although if you only want to iterate `arrB` in a `foreach` statement, you can avoid the copy by omitting `ToArray()`

Comment: Array.ConvertAll has this covered already http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx

Comment: @bottlenecked: excellent point. `ConvertAll` *will* do the same thing as my example. It won't, however, allow for iteration against the array as a different type without copying the array, which a simple call to `Cast` will allow. If a copy is needed, `ConvertAll`. If iteration is needed, `Cast`.

Answer (score 6):

Array covariance only works for reference types and in the inheritance hierarchy (note that it's not a representation-changing conversion: just a set of pointers with identical size interpreted differently.) It will not work for value types and user defined conversions.

Comment: @Randolpho: Not true. Array covariance has been around since .NET 1.0. It's not statically checked safe co/contra-variance for *generics* that's new in .NET 4.

Comment: Can't I write an implicit cast method that casts from A[] to B[] ?
I don't mind having to loop through the array and casting each object individually into the other array.
Can't it be done? (I can't seem to find the syntax for that...)

Comment: @Malki: if you don't mind a loop and cast/copy, just use my suggested answer; the methods I mention will do the loop and copy for you.

Comment: @Randolpho: Thanks, that does help, but I really was looking for a way to do that implicitly... :\

Comment: @Malki: keep in mind that your implicit operator doesn't actually cast; it's instantiating a new object. Granted, that object references the original item, but it's still, essentially, a shallow copy. You may be better off reconsidering your approach and going with the explicit cast.

Answer (score 4):

### ConvertAll

Just to be explicit, here is how you use ConvertAll.

In the case where `class B` has a member of `class A` called `m_a`, do this:

```
B[] arrB;
A[] arrA = Array.ConvertAll(arrB, b => b.m_a);
```

.

If `class B` has some member data that you need to manipulate before you can return an object of type A (such as turning a bunch of numerical values into a string description), do this:

```
class B
{        
    public static A makeAfromB(B b)
    {
        // Do something with B data...

        A a = new A("data made from B data")
        return a;
    }

    // rest of class B implementation ...
}

// somewhere else in your code...
A[] arrA = Array.ConvertAll(arrB, new Converter<B, A>(B.makeAfromB));
```

.

You can also use Lambda functions:

```
A[] arrA = Array.ConvertAll(arrB, new Converter<B, A>(
    delegate(B b)
    {
        // Do something with B data, though object b is const

        A a = new A("data made from B data")
        return a;
    }));
```

.

It would be nice if ConvertAll could use the implicit operator to do the conversion, but I haven't figured out how to do that.

.

### Cast

@Randolpho @bottlenecked

For the cases where you simply want to iterate and would prefer not to make a copy, using cast makes sense. However I have been unable to make it work.

I have an `InkPoint` class which has a `Point` object and some other members. I want to call the `DrawLines(Pen, Point[])` function. However, I have an array of `InkPoint[]`.

Here is my class and the code I currently have to use, which makes a copy:

```
public class InkPoint
{
    public InkPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        point = new Point(x, y);
    }

    public Point point { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Point(InkPoint p)
    {
        return p.point;
    }
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    InkPoint[] inkPoints = { new InkPoint(1,2), new InkPoint(3,4) };
    Point[] points = Array.ConvertAll(inkPoints, x => x.point);

    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points);
}
```

.

I would rather call this, but it won't compile, citing invalid arguments:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, inkPoints.Cast<Point>()); // Compile err: invalid args
```

.

I've also tried iterating over a cast, but it throws an exception, citing the cast is not valid

```
foreach (Point p in inkPoints.Cast<Point>()) { } // Exception: cast not valid
```

.

I don't understand why the `specified cast is not valid` since I've defined an implicit operator. I'm able to do the following just fine:

```
InkPoint ip = new InkPoint(10, 20);
Point p1 = ip; // implicit conversion
Point p2 = (Point)ip; // cast
```

.

For me, the situation is actually slightly more complicated than that. I actually have a list of InkPoints, `List<InkPoint>`, but the `DrawLines` function accepts only arrays. So my code looks like this:

```
List<InkPoint> inkPoints = new List<InkPoint>();
inkPoints.Add(new InkPoint(5, 10));
inkPoints.Add(new InkPoint(10, 15));
Point[] points = inkPoints.ConvertAll<Point>(x => x.point).ToArray();
```

I can rearrange it slightly to this:

```
Point[] points = Array.ConvertAll(inkPoints.ToArray(), x => x.point);
```

.

So I think there's actually two copies happening here. This is annoying since all I want to do is draw the lines. It doesn't seem unreasonable that the `DrawLines` function should be able to iterate over some array/list that contains references to objects that can be implicitly converted to `Point` objects.

Comment: `Point` is a struct (not a reference type) - because of the way valuetype semantics works this means that your implicit cast is also making a copy. In short you can't avoid a copy in this case. Even if Point was a reference type the `Cast<T>` extension returns an Enumerable<T>, not an array, so it's not really useful in this case. The only way to do what you want is to rethink the fundamental design so you are storing arrays of points to begin with. (With InkPoint possibly being a sort of viewer into a specific element of such a collection.) But that's a lot of work. Do you _really_ need it?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine for a moment if Arrays used the same syntax as other collections in .Net, and what you're trying to compare is an `Array<A>` with an `Array<B>`. You wouldn't compare a `List<A>` to a `List<B>`. Well, that's essentially what you're trying.

I'd recommend using a simple extension method to get the result you want, you'll need to change your syntax slightly to say 'B[] arrB = arrA.ToBArray();`

```
static class ArrayCast {
    public static B[] ToBArray(this A[] source) {
        var result = new B[source.Length];
        for (int i = 0;i < source.Length;i++)
            result[i] = source[i];
        return result;
    }
}
```