# How to Implicitly Convert an Enumerable of a type with Implicit Conversion Operators in C# 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, ienumerable, implicit-conversion

Given:

```
public struct Id
{
    readonly int m_id;

    public Id(int id)
    { m_id = id; }

    public static implicit operator int(Id id)
    { return id.m_id; }

    public static implicit operator Id(int id)
    { return new Id(id); }
}
```

Can you implicitly convert an

```
IEnumerable<int>
```

to

```
IEnumerable<Id>
```

and vice versa. In some way. Note that

```
var ids = new int[]{ 1, 2 };
ids.Cast<Id>();
```

does not appear to work and covariance does not appear to be working in this case, either. Of course, doing a select will work i.e.:

```
ids.Select(id => new Id(id));
```

But I am looking for something that would make this work implicitly, so writing:

```
IEnumerable<Id> ids = new int[]{ 1, 2 };
```

And yes, I know this can be written as:

```
IEnumerable<Id> ids = new Id[]{ 1, 2 };
```

But the issue is in cases where the enumerable of ints comes from a different source, such as a file for example.

I am sorry if there already is an answer for this, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047727/implicit-array-casting-in-c/3047759#3047759) what you want is not possible. But you can get close by not implicitly casting your id but your collection. Like this :

```
public class Ids : List<int>
{
    public static implicit operator Ids(int[] intArray)
    {
        var result = new Ids();
        result.AddRange(intArray);
        return result;
    }
}
```

then this is possible :

```
Ids t = new [] { 3,4 };
```

Comment: Yes, I do not think it is possible either, I just wanted to be sure. Well, the whole point of having the "Id" type is to make the code more explicit. Thus, to remove the use of int and instead use Id (or similar) making the code more readable. I guess your suggestion could be combined with this, though.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
IEnumerable<int> data = GetDataFromSource();
IEnumerable<Id> ids = data.select(id => new Id(id));
```

Comment: Nothing as such, as I said I know this is how you can do it. It just seems stupid since the compiler should know that the transformation from IEnumerable<int> to IEnumerable<Id> is possible and with covariance even feasible.